# How to switch power schemes intelligently using a .bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make a smart switch code that basically gets the power scheme list to define which one is active to change between two schemes.

---

**I did some research and wrote this:**

powercfg /list

if active == b3b9f3ad-d2cd-4a8f-8aae-a99c8d78d9c2 do powercfg /s c1d98a88-6636-49fe-a41e-45d639b23933

if active == c1d98a88-6636-49fe-a41e-45d639b23933 do powercfg /s b3b9f3ad-d2cd-4a8f-8aae-a99c8d78d9c2

---

*(The GUIDs are my power plans.)

But this code doesn't work for some reason.

---

*[power plan info picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ngvc.png)

Comment: One problem is `if` doesn't have a `Do` component. See `If /?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assess the value of the active power scheme, you need to isolate it from the `powercfg /list` commands output. That is achieved with a for /F loop:

```bat
@Echo off
  Set "Scheme1=b3b9f3ad-d2cd-4a8f-8aae-a99c8d78d9c2"
  Set "Scheme2=c1d98a88-6636-49fe-a41e-45d639b23933"
  for /F "Tokens=4 delims= " %%A in ('powercfg /List') Do (
    If /I "%%~A"=="%Scheme1%" (powercfg /s %Scheme2%) Else powercfg /s %Scheme1%
  )
```

Comment: So this script solved half of the issue. It switches from high performance to power saving but doesn't do the other way. I don't know if it was intended but thanks for your time because i don't think i could do even half of it true myself and i don't really understand all of it.

Comment: I did this to try and solve the issue. It switches from "high performance" to "power saving" but when trying other way it very quickly switches from "power saving" to "high performance" and switches back to "power saving".      --------      @ Echo off
  Set "Scheme1=b3b9f3ad-d2cd-4a8f-8aae-a99c8d78d9c2"
  Set "Scheme2=c1d98a88-6636-49fe-a41e-45d639b23933"
  for /F "Tokens=4 delims= " %%A in ('powercfg /List') Do (
    If /I "%%~A"=="%Scheme1%" (powercfg /s %Scheme2%) Else powercfg /s %Scheme1%
    If /I "%%~A"=="%Scheme2%" (powercfg /s %Scheme1%) Else powercfg /s %Scheme2%
  )   @T3RR0R